# How to suppress logging in spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm using `spacy` right now to process some non-English text data. An example of the code snippet is below

```
nlp = spacy.load('fr')
pos = POSTagger()
french_lemmatizer = LefffLemmatizer(after_melt=True, default=True)
nlp.add_pipe(pos, name='pos', after='parser')
nlp.add_pipe(french_lemmatizer, name='lefff', after='pos')
doc = nlp(u"Apple cherche a acheter une startup anglaise pour 1 milliard de dollard")
for d in doc:
    print(d.text, d.pos_, d._.melt_tagger, d._.lefff_lemma, d.tag_, d.lemma_)
```

Whenever I run that code, it outputs these logs

```
2020-11-05 17:35:00,497 - spacy_lefff.melt_tagger - INFO -   TAGGER: Loading lexicon...
2020-11-05 17:35:01,115 - spacy_lefff.melt_tagger - INFO -   TAGGER: Loading tags...
2020-11-05 17:35:01,152 - spacy_lefff.melt_tagger - INFO -   TAGGER: Loading model from /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/computer_vision_playground/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy_lefff/data/tagger/models/fr...
2020-11-05 17:35:01,853 - spacy_lefff.melt_tagger - INFO -   TAGGER: Loading model from /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/computer_vision_playground/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy_lefff/data/tagger/models/fr: done
2020-11-05 17:35:01,857 - spacy_lefff.lefff - INFO - New LefffLemmatizer instantiated.
2020-11-05 17:35:01,859 - spacy_lefff.lefff - INFO - Reading lefff data...
2020-11-05 17:35:02,472 - spacy_lefff.lefff - INFO - Successfully loaded lefff lemmatizer
2020-11-05 17:35:02,549 - spacy_lefff.melt_tagger - INFO -   TAGGER: POS Tagging...
```

Now, I need to use this POS tagger for thousands of text and I need to iterate through them one by one. The printing of these logs might be too much for a Jupyter Notebook, hence I want to suppress them and use progress monitor package `tqdm` which is easy to use on for loops. Is there any way to suppress the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue isn't with `spacy` and is with the logging of `spacy-lefff` package. For other users of the library and might want to suppress it, I simply set the warning level of the `spacy-lefff` package to suppress the logs. The snippet is below

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("spacy_lefff").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```